# How can I perform a JavaScript function defined into a .js file included in my page from the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following doubt.

Into a JSP page I include a .js file that contains a function definition, in this way:

```
<script src="<c:url value="resources/js/userAgentInfo.js" />"></script>
```

Into this **userAgentInfo.js** file I have define a function, something like this:

```
function exludeUserAgent() {

    ...............................................
    ...............................................
    ...............................................

    if (browserName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && majorVersion <= 10) {
        alert("EXCLUDE");
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

OK, now my problem is: how can I call and perform this **exludeUserAgent()** function into my page? I have included the file that contain its definition but now I want to perform it when the page is loaded.

Comment: One option is: `window.onload = exludeUserAgent;`

Comment: Are you wanting to exclude functionality based on a specific feature?  If so, I'd suggest feature detection instead of User agent sniffing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the below code in your JSP page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   exludeUserAgent()
});
</script>
```

Comment: The question has no `jquery` tag, so your answer seems to be irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Just use this single block in your webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> exludeUserAgent();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery in your page try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   exludeUserAgent()
});
</script>
```

if no jQuery is available you can try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        exludeUserAgent();
    };
</script>
```

both script blocks just need to be part of your jsp

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I attach an event to the `onload` event of the window. This will be fired whenever all the resources *initially present* on the page have loaded (css/html/images/sounds/videos).

To do this, you simply need do the following:

`window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);`

Next, you need a function that will actually handle this event:

```
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
   /* initialization code goes here */
}
```

In your case, you'd just need to add a call to the `exludeUserAgent` function to the body of `onDocLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

Wy to wait until the page load?
I think you want to do that immediately when your script file loads.

Just add call to the function on the script file:

```
exludeUserAgent()
function exludeUserAgent() {

    ...............................................
    ...............................................
    ...............................................

    if (browserName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && majorVersion <= 10) {
        alert("EXCLUDE");
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**One more note:** As you can see you can call the function before you defined it. This is how JavaScript works...